# MS-DOS executable's [mov] instruction dynamic relocating at entry point

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, relocation, memory-segmentation

I've disassembled a MS-DOS Executable(16-bits) in IDA, the first instruction at entry point is

```nasm
mov ax, 0x1000 ;  B8 00 10
```

However, when dumping raw hex, the corresponding field is

```nasm
mov ax, 0x0000 ;  B8 00 00
```

Is there any dynamic relocation occurring after loading the program?

Comment: What sort of DOS executable is this?  A COM? Or an EXE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmode executable files are linked to linear address **0**, as if the entire megabyte of memory was their. Which of course isn't, there are 256 bytes of interrupt table at the address **0**, followed by BIOS data area, resident programs etc.
When the program loader allocates available memory, it will know the *image base*, i.e. the starting linear address. Then it will load the contents of EXE file to this memory and looks at the relocation table in *MZ header*. The table is an array of FAR pointers to WORDS now loaded in memory, which need to be elevated by image base. In [this EXE description](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/exe/) is the table named `EXE_RELOC`.

Yes, the entry instruction `mov ax, @data` is assembled and linked as `mov ax,0` but the immediate **0** in its body is marked as *to be relocated on load*. We can see the relocated value in debugger after loading the program.

Comment: This applies to MZ (EXE) type executables only.  COM type executables do not have relocation tables.

Comment: @fuz Indeed, but OP wonderred why was the word relocated, so his program evidently isn't COM.

Comment: OPs observation could come from something else.  I do not want to make unfounded assumptions and OP refused to clarify.